# Is there a way to overwrite a value contained within a config.properties file via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, properties, jenkins-plugins, config, properties-file

Is there a way to overwrite a value contained within a config.properties file via Jenkins?

I have the following config.properties file contained within my automation framework:
browser=chrome
url=http//www.example.com

If the value of chrome get changed to firefox then all tests will now execute within firefox browser.

I can manually change this value by directly accessing the config.properties file but can the value get altered via jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin to read properties files, and it looks like it can write a few other types of files, but not properties files.

It seems to me that you want to make this change in this file so you can run some tests first in one browser, then in another. If this is the case, I think a better way to handle this is to try to get your tests to point to different files. This is a little cleaner, and allows things like parallel execution and when you find that another thing needs to change in the future, you won't be writing so many things to the file in a script, which gets a little error prone.

If you can't make your tests execute against a different properties file, you could have a copy of each file you need, and then copy them to them appropriate filename to execute your tests.

But maybe I made poor assumptions as to your setup here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can create a build parameter as $browser to accept the value say "firefox" and using sed inside "execute shell", replace the value in config.properties.
Once done, execute your scripts.

This is just overview as you have not posted details about your config.properties file, its location, if you are using Jenkins jobs or jenkinsfile/pipeline etc.